# How to give a 200 response from elasticsearch without authentication to an app gateway?

Tags: azure, elasticsearch

I have an issue setting up an ES cluster on Azure. I'd like my cluster to be behind an application gateway and also use shield authentication.

The problem is that the azure application gateway needs to send a health ping to the cluster and get back a 200 response, otherwise it returns a 502 "bad gateway". If I create an anonymous use then I can get the cluster to return a 200 but I'd rather not enable an anonymous user and use basic authentication instead.

Is there some endpoint on the cluster that will return a 200 even if the user is not authenticated and anonymous users are turned off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is no such endpoint in Elasticsearch**. There is `status.allowAnonymous` in Kibana for the stats api endpoint, but nothing similar in Elasticsearch.

You'd have to define your own user that has access to a specific healthcheck url and use that or anonymous access enabled.

The healthchecks story can have variations: you check the health of a specific node (`/_cluster/health?local=true`), or the health of the cluster. You can also get a 200 if you send a `_search` request (with `preference=_local`) to a specific node even if that cluster doesn't have an elected master node, for example, because [by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html#no-master-block) a _search operation is permitted on a node even in such situation.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Andrei's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43270515/1831), I'd recommend taking a look at [Elastic's Azure ARM template](https://github.com/elastic/azure-marketplace) which can deploy a cluster with Application Gateway configured for load balancing and SSL offload to the cluster.

This also works with [X-Pack Security](https://www.elastic.co/products/x-pack/security) by setting up anonymous access for the Application Gateway ping health check that is assigned a role with access only to

```
cluster:
    - cluster:monitor/main
```

It would be great if the ping check supported supplying credentials in the future, in which case anonymous access would not be required, locking things down further.

To deploy a cluster with Application Gateway using Azure PowerShell

```bsh
function PromptCustom($title, $optionValues, $optionDescriptions)
{
    Write-Host $title
    Write-Host
    $a = @()
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $optionValues.Length; $i++){
        Write-Host "$($i+1))" $optionDescriptions[$i]
    }
    Write-Host

    while($true)
    {
        Write-Host "Choose an option: "
        $option = Read-Host
        $option = $option -as [int]

        if($option -ge 1 -and $option -le $optionValues.Length)
        {
            return $optionValues[$option-1]
        }
    }
}

function Prompt-Subscription() {
    # Choose subscription. If there's only one we will choose automatically
    $subs = Get-AzureRmSubscription
    $subscriptionId = ""

    if($subs.Length -eq 0) {
        Write-Error "No subscriptions bound to this account."
        return
    }

    if($subs.Length -eq 1) {
        $subscriptionId = $subs[0].SubscriptionId
    }
    else {
        $subscriptionChoices = @()
        $subscriptionValues = @()

        foreach($subscription in $subs) {
            $subscriptionChoices += "$($subscription.SubscriptionName) ($($subscription.SubscriptionId))";
            $subscriptionValues += ($subscription.SubscriptionId);
        }

        $subscriptionId = PromptCustom "Choose a subscription" $subscriptionValues $subscriptionChoices
    }

    return $subscriptionId
}

$subscriptionId = "{YOUR SUBSCRIPTION ID}"

try {
    Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Please Login"
    Login-AzureRmAccount
    $subscriptionId = Prompt-Subscription
    Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
}

# Specify the template version to use. This can be a branch name, commit hash, tag, etc.
# NOTE: different template versions may require different parameters to be passed, so be sure to check 
# the parameters/password.parameters.json file in the respective tag branch 
$templateVersion = "master"

$templateSrc = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/azure-marketplace/$templateVersion/src"
$elasticTemplate = "$templateSrc/mainTemplate.json"
$location = "Australia Southeast"
$resourceGroup = "app-gateway-cluster"
$name = $resourceGroup   
$cert = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("{PATH TO cert.pfx}"))

$clusterParameters = @{
    "artifactsBaseUrl"= $templateSrc
    "esVersion" = "5.1.2"
    "esClusterName" = $name
    # Deploy to same location as Resource Group location
    "location" = "ResourceGroup"
    # Install X-Pack plugins.
    # Will install trial license
    "xpackPlugins" = "Yes"
    # Use Application Gateway
    "loadBalancerType" = "gateway"
    "vmDataDiskCount" = 2
    "dataNodesAreMasterEligible" = "Yes"
    "adminUsername" = "russ"
    "authenticationType" = "password"
    "adminPassword" = "{Super Secret Password}"
    "securityAdminPassword" = "{Super Secret Admin User Password}"
    "securityReadPassword" = "{Super Secret Read User Password}"
    "securityKibanaPassword" = "{Super Secret Kibana User Password}"
    "appGatewayCertBlob" = $cert
    "appGatewayCertPassword" = "{Password for cert.pfx (if it has one)}"
}

Write-Host "[$(Get-Date -format 'u')] Deploying cluster"
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup -Location $location
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $name -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -TemplateUri $elasticTemplate -TemplateParameterObject $clusterParameters
Write-Host "[$(Get-Date -format 'u')] Deployed cluster"
```

Take a look at the other [parameters available for the template](https://github.com/elastic/azure-marketplace#parameters) which can be used to control other elements such as size and number of disks to attach to each data node, setting up Azure Cloud plugin for snapshot/restore, etc.